# Order Repository save not working

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, magento2.2.6, repositories

I am trying to associate orders and customer using the following code.

```
$order = $this->orderRepo->get($oid);
$order->setCustomerId($newCustomer->getId());
$order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
$this->orderRepo->save($order);
```

Where orderRepo is `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`

But save is not working as expected and I can’t see association in order details page/customer order section.

I have checked in the `create` method in `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CustomerManagement` and Magento is doing the same.

Comment: try to put code into try.....catch block, so if any error then it show there.

Comment: Does it save in the db?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Nothing in try catch block.

Comment: @acf No, it is not saving in db as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was because some other module was loading the order object using `Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory` and setting some data and then calling `save` method of it.

I have solved my problem by calling my method after this module's processing.